# Vuejs build/render component inside a method and output into template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a string (example, because it's an object with many key/values, want to loop and append to htmloutput) with a component name. Is it possible to render/build the component inside a method and display the html output?

Is that possible and how can i achieve that?

```html
     <template>
         <div v-html="htmloutput"></div>
     </template>


<script>
    export default {
        component: {
            ComponentTest
        },
    data() {
            return {
                htmloutput: ''
            }
        },
    methods:{
        makeHtml(){
            let string = 'component-test';//ComponentTest
            //render the ComponentTest directly
            this.htmloutput = ===>'HERE TO RENDER/BUILD THE COMPONENTTEST'<==
        }
    },
    created(){
            this.makeHtml();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for dynamic components:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

Example:

```html
<template>
    <component :is="changeableComponent">
    </component>
</template>

<script>
    import FirstComponent from '@/views/first';
    import SecondComponent from '@/views/second';

    export default {
        components: {
            FirstComponent, SecondComponent
        },
        computed: {
            changeableComponent() {
                // Return 'first-component' or 'second-component' here which corresponds
                // to one of the 2 included components.
                return 'first-component';
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, i know this but i want to render it into a method and append the component html to htmloutput

Comment: i dont quite see what you want to do. Appending content can be done using different tags in your template right?

Comment: I want to call makeHtml and render, created() calls makeHtml()

Comment: `render()` is an alternative to string templates. Loading another component will create a template either through `render()` or the vue compiler will find your `<template>` element in that same file.

Comment: How can i achieve that?

Comment: You dont need to use `render()`, you need to create a new component and include it in the `components` key and reference it that way. I cant help you any further im afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the [render](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html) function for that here is an example :

```js
Vue.component('CompnentTest', {
  data() {
    return {
      text: 'some text inside the header'
    }
  },
  render(createElement) {
    return createElement('h1', this.text)
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <Compnent-test />
</div>
```

**Or :**

if you are using `Vue-cli` :

**on your `componentTest` component :**

```js
export default {
  render(createElement) {
    return createElement('h1', 'sometext')
  }
  // Same as
  // <template>
  //   <h1>sometext</h1>
  // </template>
  //
}
```

**and on your root element (`App.vue` as default) :**

```js
export default {
   ....
  component: {
    ComponentTest
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
      ....
     <Component-test />
  </div>
</template>
```

example  : [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-hh7ji)

you can read more about
[Render Functions & JSX](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html)

Comment: How can i achieve this in my example?

Comment: @Bas on your `ComponentTest` you can create the render function and then just import the component and use it on your template

Comment: @Bas i will update the answer for a vue-cli project

Comment: Sorry don't understand it, can you use my example?

Comment: @Bas yes here is an example : [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-hh7ji)  check the `component`

Comment: please consider reading more about render function.. you can do more than just creating a simple header ... you can use it instead of your template as shown on the answer

Comment: This is not want i want, <component-test msg="Hello Vue in CodeSandbox!"/> into my template. It has to render inside makeHtml function/method and append the html

Comment: @Bas it is doing that actually on the component that `msg="Hello Vue in CodeSandbox!"` is just a bound value to the component you can remove it .... if you want to use the example you provided you can just do this `this.htmloutput= "<p>+ string +</p>"`

Comment: string is the component which has to be render, so component-test has to render ComponentTest directly into the method makeHtml()

Comment: @Bas when you import a component it will be already rendered you just need to place it inside your parent template

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197732/discussion-between-bas-and-dadboz).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help - https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-can-i-get-rendered-html-code-of-vue-component/19421

StarRating is a sample Vue component. You can get it HTML code by run:

```
new Vue({
  ...StarRating,
  parent: this,
  propsData: { /* pass props here*/ }
}).$mount().$el.outerHTML
```

in Your method. Remember about `import Vue from 'vue';` and of course import component.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do really isn't best practice for Vue.

It's better to use `v-if` and `v-for` to conditionally render your component in the `<template>` section.